# Template argument deduction and pointers to constants

Tags: c++, templates

I had defined two overloaded functions, their declarations are as follows

```
template <class T> void Foo(const T *p);    // lets call this Foo_p

template <class T> void Foo(const T& r);    // lets call this Foo_r
```

When I call

`Foo( ptr_to_non_const );`

`Foo_r` gets called. I assumed that constant qualification are stripped away from pointers when looking for best match. Since `T*` is more specialized than `T&` I expected that `Foo_p` will be called.

Could anyone point me to a good resource that lists template argument deduction rules and the precedence of matches.

In this particular case I intend `template <class T> void Foo(const T& r)` to be called for non-pointer type. Does it mean I have to define the functions with and without `const` qualifications. For one argument it is not a big deal, but my function take more than one pointer, so I would want to avoid the repition. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409 ("The C++ Template Argument Deduction" Overload Journal #48 - Apr 2002 + Programming Topics   Author: Andrei Iltchenko).

Comment: @bn yeah thats the only one nearly exhaustive that I could find. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template deduction rules are quite complicated and I'm not sure if there is anywhere a simple summary. However, if two templates are candidates and one of them requires a conversion while the other does not, the one not requiring a conversion to produce the template argument is chosen. In your example, the matching instantiations are thus:

```
S* ptr_to_non_const = ...;
Foo(ptr_to_non_const); // => candidates:
                       //   a. F(const T&) with `T` deduced as `S*` requires no
                       //      conversion
                       //   b. F(const T*) with `T` deduced as `S` requires `S*` to
                       //      `S const*` conversion
```

To force the use of the pointer overload, you can remove the reference version from the overload set using `std::enable_if<...>` together with `std::is_pointer<...>`:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type
Foo(const T& r);
```

Although this uses the C++ 2011 features, both `std::enable_if<...>` and `std::is_pointer<...>` can be implemented quite easy with a C++ 2003 compiler, as well (and I'm pretty sure that [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) has done so).

Comment: Thanks and I have been searching for description of template deduction rules, nothing comprehensive comes up. I guess I have to go to the standards, not sure if it will be available online, may be a draft.

Comment: It seems someone pointed to an article in [Overload](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c78/): the articles in past volumes are accessible for free.